# rakefile task does not accept second parameters

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I have piece of code from my rakefile. Few tasks have to have multiple parameters.

```
desc 'confidential'
  task :task1, [:targetPrj, :arg1] do |t,args|
  args.with_defaults(:arg1 => "0")
  TARGET_PROJECT = args[:targetPrj]
  TEST_SW = args[:emcTest]
  makeApp(t)
end
```

If I call `rake task1[TARGET _1]` everything is OK, but if I add second parameter rake `task1[TARGET _1, 5]` then I get:

```
Rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task task1[TARGET_1, '
```

I really do not know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters should be separated by commas **without spaces**:

```
task1[TARGET_1,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are separated by spaces and rake treats each argument as a separate task. This would run tasks `foo` and `bar`:

```
rake foo bar
```

If you have:

```
rake task1[TARGET_1, 5]
```

then rake gets two arguments: `task1[TARGET_1,` and `5]`. Trying to parse these strings results in an error.

To get the correct result, you can remove the space, escape the space, or put the argument in quotes:

```
rake task1[TARGET_1,5]
rake task1[TARGET_1,\ 5]
rake "task1[TARGET_1, 5]"
```

Note that this behavior isn't rake specific, that's how command line arguments work in general.